# appending complete html of one dive into new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery for this: 
Taking complete html and appending into a new div

My JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addNew").click(function(){
        var maindiv = document.getElementById('nestedFeilds').html();
        $("#showhere").append('maindiv');
    });
});
```

The HTML is pretty complex and lengthy so take just reference

```
<div class= "row" id="mainContainer">
    <label for="Education" style="margin-left: 30px ; float:left;">Education</label>

        <div class="col-xs-4 inner"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds"  style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none;">
```

In the last div, it is actually a form and I need its complete html to be shown with different name attribute when ever I click button

I am calling my function like this

```
<div id= "showhere"></div>
<div  style="margin-left: 133px;float:left;">
    <a id="addNew"> Add Education</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So two things from your first block.  `html()` is a jquery method.  But you are doing a vanilla lookup.  If you want to leave it like that, use `innerHTML` rather than `html()`.  Otherwise, turn it into a jquery object to use `html()`.  Secondly, you are appending the string 'maindiv', not the variable.  Take off the quotes to use the variable.  Edit: and ironically 'Fields' is misspelled as part of your id value, which is inside your label for 'Education' .... but that's just me chuckling, ^_^

Comment: okay thankyou let me edit my code

Comment: sir it is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get `innerHTML`, you should use `element.innerHTML`, and if you want to append previously saved inner HTML, you can use `element.append(variableWithPreviousInnerHTML)`. Here is the working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    var maindiv = document.getElementById('nestedFeilds').innerHTML;
    $("#showhere").append(maindiv);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nestedFeilds">Content from #nestedFeilds</div>
<div id="showhere"></div>
<button id="addNew">Click</button>
```

If anything isn't clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: @ramii, new problem = new question, it's SO policy

Comment: the div which i want to clone is positioned and styled to col-md-8 of a row and where i am showing through java script is  out of style and position